Analyze pdf file with openai API
I'm trying to upload a PDF file with chatPGT API and ask it if the file contain a specific word but It seems to not see that a gave it a file.
To upload the file, I used this code
$pdfFile contains a correct path to the pdf file.
ch = curl_init(https://api.openai.com/v1/files);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Authorization: Bearer ' . $api_key));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array(
    'purpose' => 'assistants',
    'file' => new CURLFile($pdfFile),
));
$response_upload = curl_exec($ch);
$info_upload = curl_getinfo($ch);
curl_close($ch);

response contain a valid id : for example file-lbNMtTgJHW01QZxRZXarx2Ve
I tried to ask my question
$file_id = 'file-lbNMtTgJHW01QZxRZXarx2Ve';

$data = array(
'model' => $model,
'messages' => array(
    array('role' => 'system', 'content' => 'Vous êtes un assistant'),
    array(
        'role' => 'user',
        'content' => 'Does this PDF file contain the word XXXX',
    'file_ids' => [$file_id]
   ))
);

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $api_url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($data));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    'Content-Type: application/json',
    'Authorization: Bearer ' . $api_key
));

And the reply is something like
For me to help you determine if a file contains the expressed word you must provide the contents of the file or a file
Has anyone ever asked ChatGPT to analyze the content of a PDF file?
I specify that if I use chapGPT online, it works very well
Thank's

From your code it's not clear which API Endpoint you are using for the second call after the file upload. By the parameters looks like you are calling chat/completions, but at this point they don't support PDF vision only image vision, e.g only image inputs. Here's the doc reference.
To work with PDFs in OpenAI you need to use the Assistants API.
However I assume assistants is not what you are looking for, because it's a bit over complicated for your case - you need to create assistant, then upload a file, then making a thread and then posting a message.
If I understand correctly you just simply want to send over a PDF file (different file every time) and analyse it without storing the thread.
To achieve that I can suggest you to try out Gemini. The model have vision for all kind of documents, images, audio and video. And you can send a simple prompt with file upload in a single request.
Here's example reading PDF with Gemini using AIpi - Universal API client for common AI models:
use AIpi\Thread;
use AIpi\Message;
use AIpi\MessageType;

$my_google_key = 'my_google_key';

/* ************************************************/
/* Analysing files with Gemini ********************/
/* It supports documents, images, audio and video */
/* ************************************************/
$thread = new Thread('google-gemini-1.5-flash', $my_google_key);

// Send PDF file for understanding
$pdf = file_get_contents('https://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-pdf/f4506.pdf');
$thread->AddMessage(new Message($pdf, ['type' => MessageType::FILE, 'media_type' => 'application/pdf']));
$thread->AddMessage(new Message('How to fill out this form for my personal tax return? ', ['type' => MessageType::TEXT]));


$message = $thread->Run();
if ($message) 
{
    echo $message->content."\r\n";
    print_r($thread->GetUsage());
    echo "\r\n\r\n";
}
else echo $thread->GetLastError();


Yes, I agree. This is the approach in OpenAI if you don't want to use agents api, but simply analyse the pdf contents. However that involves using pdf text extracting tool. In same cases the text content in the pdf files (like scanned documents) is created as image, so you will need OCR tool in addition. It's far more complicated than the author of the post expects. This is the reason I suggested switching to Gemini as you can just upload the document with your prompt and let the model handle it. I'm sure OpenAI will implement that anytime soon, but it's just not available right now.
